# Styletron build process

Tags: reactjs, styletron

I'm looking to choose a css-in-js library and so far styletron looks like the most performant and lightweight

My concern is if we don't render the react application server side, it will add too much overhead on the client.

Is that a correct assumption? Is there another way?

A friend mentioned its possible to implement that in the build process, but can't find anything related.